# AVPlayerViewController and AVPlayer in swift doesn't show anything

Tags: ios, swift, mp4, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm trying to play an mp4 video from documents path in a **AVPlayerViewController** with an **AVPlayer** but it doesn't appear anything on screen.What am I doing wrong?

Here a screenshot of the simulator: http://postimg.org/image/xma60nfrf/

and this is my code:

```
func startPlayer(filePath:String)
{
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask, true)
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0]


    let filePath = (docsDir as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(videos[videoNo]._Name)

    playerVC=AVPlayerViewController()
    playerVC!.view.frame=self.view.bounds
    playerVC!.view.layer.zPosition = 1;


    var videoURL = NSURL(string: filePath)
    var player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)
    var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = playerVC!.view.bounds
    playerVC!.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    playerVC!.player=player
    self.view.addSubview(playerVC!.view)

    playerVC!.player!.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AVAsset` as source for player.

```
let currentVideoAsset = AVAsset(URL: outputFileURL)


self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset:currentVideoAsset))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it,I replaced this

```
var videoURL = NSURL(string: filePath)
```

with this

```
var videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
```

and is working..